# Lack of response by FinCen?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, foreign-currency, government

I had all my FBAR information prepared well before the deadline to file.  In order to avoid electronic signatures, I requested a paper FBAR, and received one.  The paper FBAR contained instructions how to fill if I have 3 bank accounts or less, and instructions if I have 25 or more.  I have 4.

I contacted the FinCen via https://www.fincen.gov/contact, asking how to fill the paper out in this case.  A month later the deadline to file has passed, and I received no response.  Despite the instructions on the web saying only one contact method should be used, I decided to call and leave a message, in case my query got lost.  I left a message.  Now, 2 more months later, no response to either the filled form or to the call.

The deadline is passed, and I have had this information ready all along, and it seems silly to be not filing because I do not know how to report 4 bank accounts correctly.  But at the same time, I do not wish to mis-report something, and face penalties because of that.  Is there anything I can do to get FinCen to respond?

p.s., my salary for the entire year is less than $2000, because I work slowly and companies don't keep me hired on.  I am not getting any government assistance such as food stamps or medicare.  So hiring a lawyer is out of the question for me.

Comment: Where dies it say anything about 3 bank accounts or less? The instructions are available [here](https://www.fincen.gov/sites/default/files/shared/FBAR%20Line%20Item%20Filing%20Instructions.pdf). There's also the [IRS Publication 5559](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p5569.pdf).

Comment: There's only space on the paper form for 3 accounts. So I'm not sure whether I should print out multiple pages of that same page with the 3 accounts, or if I should attach the others on paper; or maybe there's an "expandable" paper form, like Canada does, where you can press a plus sign until the number of accounts on the form matches the number of accounts you have. As I said, seems silly to delay it for so long because of something so trivial, but in Canada doing it incorrectly is "misrepresentation", punishable by losing your Pernament Residence for up to 5 years; so I don't want to presume

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're an individual filer with less than 25 accounts you need to file the form with the accounts listed in Part II. If you look at [the form](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f90221.pdf), the Part II starts on the first page with the space for a single account, and then the next page has space for 5 additional accounts and is not numbered - you can print that page as many times as you need and number them in the top-right corner. In no way can I interpret this form as only having space for 3 accounts.

If you're talking about signature authority on accounts (usually for corporations), then it's part IV, which can also be printed multiple times and numbered. That one does have 3 bank accounts per page.

I'm not sure what your confusion is or why you need someone's help, but even that is not a valid excuse for late filing.

Comment: The form they sent me to use as a paper copy is Form 114SP -- since this does not seem to be available on the internet, I am not sure if they would allow me to post it here.  That form only has space for 3 accounts.  You are correct, if I use your form then there is definitely space for more accounts there.  So I think until I receive a response from FinCen, I will use your form.